# Multiply random columns by another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

I have a list that is filled by random header names of a `df`.

```
listado=['A','J']
```

`listado` can have 1 value only.

if that `listado` has values then I would like it to multiply those columns in the df by another dataframe made from 1 column called `valores`.

```
valores=df2.values

df2=
   value
0    2 
1    4  
2    3
```

the df is as it follows:

```
df=
    A  B  C  J  K
0   3  2  5  4  7  
1   5  5  5  5  5
2   9  8  5  1  7
```

Then the desired output is to multiply columns `A` and `J` by the `values` of `df2`:

```
    A  B  C  J   K
0   6  2  5  8   7  
1  20  5  5  20  5
2  27  8  5  3   7
```

I was trying something like this in order to multiply the specific columns obtained in the list:

```
if listado:
    valores=df2.values
    for units in listado:
        df1[units]=df1[units]*valores
 return df1
```

but it

```
 raise Exception('Data must be 1-dimensional')
```

and the same when I tried :

```
if listado:
    valores=df2.values
    for i in range(len(listado)):
        df1[listado[i]]=df1[listado[i]]*valores
 return df1
```

How could I obtain the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional `.loc` and `mul` on `axis=0`

```
In [496]: df.loc[:, listado] = df.loc[:, listado].mul(df2['value'], axis=0)

In [497]: df
Out[497]:
    A  B  C   J  K
0   6  2  5   8  7
1  20  5  5  20  5
2  27  8  5   3  7
```

Answer (score 3):

Using array data -

```
df[listado] = df[listado].values * df2.values
```

Sample run -

```
In [973]: df
Out[973]: 
   A  B  C  J  K
0  3  2  5  4  7
1  5  5  5  5  5
2  9  8  5  1  7

In [974]: df[listado] = df[listado].values * df2.values

In [975]: df
Out[975]: 
    A  B  C   J  K
0   6  2  5   8  7
1  20  5  5  20  5
2  27  8  5   3  7
```

Comment: Ah, this is close enough to mine... deleting

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ By few sec :)